# How to fix issue of dark theme blink in Next js 13

Tags: next.js, themes, flicker

I have a site on Next.js, Typescript, MUI, TinaCMS and Redux with dark and light themes which state is located on localStorage and changes by Redux. My default theme is dark. When I enter the page, I see for ~0.5 seconds a light theme and then a dark theme. I also have a custom document (/pages/_document.tsx) in which I add script /scripts/theme.js and ThemeProvider.

theme.js:

```js
// Code duplicate to prevent the following error:
// https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/12533

(() => {
  const defaultTheme = "dark";

  const getStorageTheme = () => {
    return localStorage.theme;
  };

  const getBrowserTheme = () => {
    if (window.matchMedia === undefined) {
      return undefined;
    }

    if (window.matchMedia("(prefers-color-scheme: light)").matches) {
      return "light";
    } else {
      return "dark";
    }
  };

  const getInitialTheme = () =>
    getStorageTheme() || getBrowserTheme() || defaultTheme;

  const theme = getInitialTheme();

  localStorage.setItem("theme", theme);

  const body = document.querySelector("body");

  if (theme === "dark") {
    body?.classList.add("dark-theme");
  } else {
    body?.classList.remove("dark-theme");
  }
})();
```

_document.tsx:

```js
/* eslint-disable @next/next/no-sync-scripts */
import { Head, Html, Main, NextScript } from "next/document";
import Script from "next/script";

const Document = () => (
  <Html lang="en">
    <Head>
      <Script src="/scripts/theme.js" strategy="beforeInteractive" />
    </Head>
    <body>
      <Main />
      <NextScript />
    </body>
  </Html>
);

export default Document;
```

/components/MUI/ThemeProvier.tsx:

```js
import { PaletteMode, ThemeProvider as MUIThemeProvider } from "@mui/material";
import { defaultTheme, setTheme, Theme } from "redux/slices/theme";
import { useAppDispatch, useAppSelector } from "redux/typesHooks";

import useIsomorphicLayoutEffect from "../useIsomorphicLayoutEffect";
import getMUITheme from "./getMUITheme";

interface Props {
  children: JSX.Element;
}

const getStorageTheme = (): Theme | undefined => {
  return localStorage.theme;
};

const getBrowserTheme = (): Theme | undefined => {
  if (window.matchMedia === undefined) {
    return undefined;
  }

  if (window.matchMedia("(prefers-color-scheme: light)").matches) {
    return "light";
  } else {
    return "dark";
  }
};

const getInitialTheme = (): Theme =>
  getStorageTheme() || getBrowserTheme() || defaultTheme;

const ThemeProvider = ({ children }: Props) => {
  const dispatch = useAppDispatch();
  const theme = useAppSelector((state) => state.theme);
  const MUITheme = getMUITheme(theme as PaletteMode);

  useIsomorphicLayoutEffect(() => {
    const initialTheme = getInitialTheme();

    dispatch(setTheme(initialTheme));
  }, [dispatch]);

  return <MUIThemeProvider theme={MUITheme}>{children}</MUIThemeProvider>;
};

export default ThemeProvider;
```

Demo: https://www.loom.com/share/04406b23e83a4490824a72515fdc9777

Github repo: https://github.com/1alexvash/AlexCodeBlog

Site url: https://alex-code.com/

I have tried [this](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/12533) solution, but it didn't help me at all.